# Ubuntu Software Center (10.04LTS) Missing Packages

Tags: software-center

I recently downgraded from 11.10 to 10.04LTS for compatibility and support of specific development tools.

The Ubuntu Software center is missing *many* packages that I had access to in 11.10, most notably LibreOffice. (Also development tools.)

Is there a way to update software sources to find the missing packages? (Or are they incompatible with 10.04?) Synaptic does not have libre either.  I feel like I am working with a gimped version of USC.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove OpenOffice and enable the PPA for LibreOffice.

Remove Openoffice

Before installing LibreOffice you need to remove existing openoffice from your system using the following command

```
sudo apt-get purge openoffice*.*
```

Install libreoffice in ubuntu 11.04/10.10/10.04 using PPA

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

For gnome users - you also need to install the following package

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gnome
```

As far a the development tools may I recommend installing "Y PPA Manager", this will allow you to search for tools and apps. Install the PPA and assist in downloading.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

[source](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/y-ppa-manager-easily-search-add-remove.html) Y-PPA

[source](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-libreoffice-in-ubuntu-11-0410-1010-04-using-ppa.html) LibreOffice

Comment: Thank You.  I had just done this, loaded Libre, then the system requested an auto update, one of the updates being updated software sources.  Now, all the familiar packages are back in USC.  Thankfully I will not have to add PPAs for each.  Since it was a new build, the system had not had a chance to update its sources.  Strangely, a large number of apt-get updates over the past day did not pick up the changes.

Comment: Not only that. To me it also was convincing! [+1]up

Comment: Please click the little green checkmark by the answer. Thanks